# How to parse string to script tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, domparser

There is DOMParser, which converts string to DOM elements, for example:

```
let htmlContentString = '<div>1</div><div>2</div>';
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlContentString , 'text/html');
let firstDiv = doc.body.firstChild;
let secondDiv = firstDiv.nextSibling;
...    
...
```

I need something similar for script tag.

Here is the flow of what I need to do: from an API, I am dynamically receiving strings (which actually represents a script snippet). Here is an example of how these strings will look like:

```
<script id="some-snippet" src="https://url.to.snippet.js?key=some-key"></script>
```

Then after I receive this string, I will need to dynamically add it into the head of the document.

- My initial issue is that I am actually not able to do this properly;
- Additional note: once the script is received, the old one should be removed and replaced with the new one;

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
function receiveScript(number) {
  let exampleScript = encodeURIComponent('<script id="some-snippet" src="https://url.to.snippet.js?key=' + String(number) + '"><\/script>');
  
  $('script.custom_script').remove();
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('class', 'custom_script');
  script.text = decodeURIComponent(exampleScript);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="receiveScript(1)">Simulate Receiving Script 1</button>
<button onclick="receiveScript(2)">Simulate Receiving Script 2</button>
```

The issue actually occurs in the line

```
script.text = decodeURIComponent(exampleScript);
```

which is actually reasonable, since I am trying to set the string which is the whole script (including the script tags).

I can not relay of the given `exampleScript` above as a reference to separate the `id` and the `src`, to parse them separately and set the parsed values in the newly created script, since the scripts that are going to be received will be of a different types and will have different properties.

That's why, will be ideal if there is some parser, that will directly convert the received string to DOM script and instead of creating `document.createElement('script');` somehow to directly parse the given string.

Comment: Sounds like a document.write would do the trick if you can get the script before you render the document (i.e. before onload triggers

Answer (score 0):

The method `encodeURIComponent` escapes some character assuming the entire string is an URL. You should set the `script.url` to the correct value.

```js
function receiveScript(number){ 
  url=`https://url.to.snippet.js?key=${number}`
  $('script.custom_script').remove();
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('class', 'custom_script');
  script.src = url; 
  
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  console.log(script)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="receiveScript(1)">Simulate Receiving Script 1</button>
<button onclick="receiveScript(2)">Simulate Receiving Script 2</button>
```